# Is this a valid way to Load/Refresh a Page on React Router Dom Link click?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

**Issue:**

I've been trying to find a way to refresh a page with React Router Dom.
I am wondering if my code below is correct and usable.

**Expected Results:**

I am trying to get the same results as when you click on an Anchor `<a href='/'>` tag with React.

**Current Code:**

Below you can find the current code I use. You will find 3 things.

1. A Reusable Link component
2. A refresh page function that refreshes at the current location.pathname
3. A Link component from React Router Dom

```
function ReusableLink({ label, address }) {        
  function refreshPage() {
    window.location.pathname.reload(false);
  }

  return (
    <li className={path === address ? 'active' : ''}> 
      <Link className='link' to={address} onClick={refreshPage}>
        {label}
      </Link>
    </li>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would only use `window.reload` in a pinch.

There are two RRD ways I know of, one each depending on the version.

If you are using `react-router-dom@6` the `Link` component has a `reloadDocument` prop.

[Link](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/components/link)

> ```
> interface LinkProps
>   extends Omit<
>     React.AnchorHTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>,
>     "href"
>   > {
>   replace?: boolean;
>   state?: any;
>   to: To;
>   reloadDocument?: boolean;
> }
> ```

You can use `<Link reloadDocument>` to skip client side routing and let the browser handle the transition normally (as if it were an `<a href>`).

```
<Link className='link' to={address} reloadDocument>
  {label}
</Link>
```

If you are using `react-router-dom@5` then the `BrowserRouter` has a `forceRefresh` prop.

[BrowserRouter](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/BrowserRouter/forcerefresh-bool)

`forceRefresh`

> If true the router will use full page refreshes on page navigation.
> You may want to use this to imitate the way a traditional
> server-rendered app would work with full page refreshes between page
> navigation.

```
<BrowserRouter forceRefresh>
  ...
</BrowserRouter>
```